# NodeJS or Asp.Net Web API for server side programming to use with Oracle DB

Tags: c#, node.js, oracle, signalr, real-time

I want design consideration on which one to use either- NodeJS or Asp.Net web api in showing real time analytics data in the UI. The backend is using Oracle DB.

Whenever there is any change in the data in db, the UI should reflect immediately. Thought of using SignalR. But the UI should get notified from db directly.

I have gone through this link for nodejs and oracle:

https://jsao.io/2015/02/real-time-data-with-node-js-socket-io-and-oracle-database/#comment-261

But this requires Linux OS, which I am not sure as always i was considering to develop on windows.

I have seen this link-Database Change Notification With ODP.NET. I am not sure if this would help me.If anyone has experience with this , please can they share their experience.

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/changenotification/ChangeNotification.htm

If anyone can guide me if i can accomplish this using Asp.net or Nodejs, it would be great.

Thanks,
WH

Comment: Why would you want to send an event or notification directly from a DB to the UI. This can be done, but is a really big anti pattern. Is it for performance reasons?

Comment: Is it possible to intercept the data as its being written to the DB and then use that for events. Using inbuilt DB mechanisms isn't really a best practice either due to performance concerns.

Comment: The solution on jsao.io does not require Linux, it just used Linux-based servers for the database and Node.js. However, both the database and Node.js are cross-platform, so the solution could be implemented on Windows. There's a link to a more recent demo of this technology here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRJLcLoLBq8. Adding direct support for this feature in the driver is on the list of things to do, which will make the setup much easier.

Comment: Thanks @DanMcGhan. I have gone through your code and 
When i run npm install i am getting this error. I have latest node(6.0) and npm(4.4) installed on my machine and using 64 bit version of node. 

npm ERR! oracledb@1.13.0 install:
node-gyp rebuild

npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the oracledb@1.13.0 install script ‘node-gyp rebuild’.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed

Comment: The driver needs to compile when installing. It's likely you don't have the latest version of the C compiler for Windows. See the prerequisite section here: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#instwin This is something we hope to make easier in the future.